# workbook can not be resolved a type in java?

Tags: java, excel, file-io, apache-poi

I am trying to read an xlsx file but I am getting the error "Work book can not be resolved a type". How to solve the same?

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream("F://myFile.xlsx"));
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
            Workbook wb1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fs)); // error is here
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);


            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while( rows.hasNext() ) {  
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                System.out.println("\n");
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
```

Comment: Have you imported Workbook ? Do you have the Apache POI jar?

Comment: What is the import statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Java cannot read Excel files directly. You need a third party library to accomplish this. From the given code, looks like you need to add the libraries from [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), specifically [POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to have all the appropriate [Apache POI component jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on your classpath. Secondly, you then need to import the POI classes.

Once you've downloaded Apache POI, and added the [components to your classpath](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), your code would then look something like:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class POIExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("F://myFile.xlsx"));
        Workbook wb1 = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            for (Cell cell : row) {
               System.out.println("Found Cell");
            }
        }
    }
}
```